# How to customize email backend for EmailMultiAlternatives in Django

Tags: django, django-settings, django-email

Background :-

My email Backend is something like this:

```
EMAIL_HOST ='smtp.gmail.com' 
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'feedback@example.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'XXX' 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Problem:-

I am using EmailMultiAlternatives to send html mails. 
Now I want to define auth_user and auth_password so that i can change the "from". Basically I want to over ride the EMAIL_HOST_USER, but want the from_email to be verbose, i.e. 'Support Team'.  How can it be done?

```
subject, from_email, to = "hello", 'Support Team','to_user@gmail.com'
text = "hello"
html = "<strong>hello</strong>"
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send(fail_silently=False,auth_user = 'support@example.me',auth_password = 'XXX')
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
from django.core.mail import *

#retrieve emailbackend from settings.py
connection = get_connection(username, password)
#change connection parameters
connection.host='XXX'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to], connection)
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
```

Comment: connection.close() is unneeded.  It will raise an error since send_messages closes any connections it opens.

Comment: I was able to use this idea to switch to a backup SMTP server when msg.send() throws an exception.  Works great.

Comment: You can pass in the connection directly.